# Cannot mount NTFS external drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab, plex, ntfs-3g

New Ubuntu Server install 20.04, for Plex Media Server (not yet installed). Popped in a USB NTFS drive which works on other machines. It has media on it which I need Plex to server. #

Attempts to mount it via fstab are not working and I cannot see any files.

blkid gives me

```
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="EXT-2TB" UUID="B8FCAECDFCAE84EA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a6928458-01"
```

Note UUID looks a bit shorter than I'd expect. The drive is readable on other machines.

fdisk -l gives me

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.84 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk model: BUP Slim BL     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa6928458

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

My fstab is below

```
UUID=B8FCAECDFCAE84EA /media/nftsdrive ntfs-3g permissions, defaults, 0 0
```

This [guidance](https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288606-mounting-ntfs-drives-on-linux/) suggests using 'auto' in the options (not 'defaults') but I understand 'defaults' includes this.  Even if I replace defaults with auto, I get same issue.

df reports :-

```
/dev/sdd1                         1953512444 1917872564  35639880  99% /media/nftsdrive
```

but `sudo ls /media/ntfsdrive` reports nothing, as if no files are there.

All the guide say I need fstab to have 'permissions' because I then need to install plex and allow the plex user access using commands like chown.

Any clues?

Comment: The UUIDs are fine for NTFS. That fstab stanza looks really malformed. Why are there blank spaces (between `permissions,` and `defaults`) and a stray comma (before the `0 0`)? Also, normally `defaults` goes first as option, followed by overrides. Have you tried interactively running `mount /media/nftsdrive` as superuser?

Comment: schoolboy error, note my typo in the mount path in fstab!

Comment: Btw, re-reading your question after your puzzling comment, I am wondering what _is_ the question? Clearly the fstab stanza is malformed, as I pointed out. So unless you swa out `permissions, defaults,` by something like `defaults` or `auto` (without comman and blank space) I don't see how it would be able to mount anything based on the stanza. Since you manage to mount successfully but don't see the contents, have you considered that it is a wholly different issue? `df` will only act on mounted volumes, so clearly you succeeded in mounting (as opposed to your question title).

Comment: Do you mean it all comes down to `nftsdrive` vs. `ntfsdrive`? That still doesn't make the list of options valid, though ...

Answer (score 1):

For starters make sure that a mount helper binary is installed for the desired file system type. It'd be `mount.ntfs-3g` in your case. If that's not the case, install it first.

If that is the case, fix your `/etc/fstab` next:

```
UUID=B8FCAECDFCAE84EA /media/nftsdrive ntfs-3g defaults,permissions 0 0
```

The  `0 0` at the end is optional (it governs the order of mounting and file system checks). Otherwise the form is:

1. source
2. target (mount point)
3. file system type
4. options

Check out [fstab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html).

Also, I have only used `ntfs` (as opposed to `ntfs-3g` in the recent few years, perhaps there's a subtle difference? But at least on my 20.04 `mount.ntfs` is a symlink to `mount.ntfs-3g`).

Last but not least you tried `ls` on `ntfsdrive` but your `fstab` stanza says `nftsdrive` ... and we don't know *which* exists as a folder and which doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I have worked this out. This is embarrassing.

I have mistyped the mount point in fstab as /media/nftsdrive not /ntfsdrive

.... Then wondered why I could not see my files in /media/ntfsdrive

I had the t and the f the wrong way around

Correcting the typo in fstab worked

Comment: So both folders existed? Because otherwise `ls` should have complained about `No such file or directory` rather than showing empty output ...

Comment: Yes both were there, that is how I realised...

I ran mkdir before amending fstab, but in the end there were two folders, so I think it automaticaly created /media/nftsdrive on boot based on fstab? Weird, because I understood that you HAD to use mkdir to create the folder before you could mount to it in fstab...

Comment: yep, that's also (still) my understanding. Very odd indeed.